# Django - If i put 2 formsets together in my view, the function to add multiple times the same views doesnt work

Tags: django, forms, view, django-templates, django-views

I have this code bellow. Im using formset to add multiple times the same form. But if i put this 2 formsets together, like in my view, just the first data for each form is saved. And if i put just 1 formset in my def, it works, all datas for i put to the form is saved. Someone have any idea why this is happening? (sorry for my eng)

Forms.py

```
class InsereIdioma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Idioma
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['usuario']
InsereIdiomaFormset = formset_factory(InsereIdioma, extra=1)

class InsereTecnologia(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tecnologia
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['usuario']
InsereTecnologiaFormset = formset_factory(InsereTecnologia, extra=1)
```

Views.py

```
def cadastro_curriculo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset_idioma = InsereIdiomaFormset(request.GET or None)
        formset_tecnologia = InsereTecnologiaFormset(request.GET or None)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset_idioma = InsereIdiomaFormset(request.POST)
        formset_tecnologia = InsereTecnologiaFormset(request.POST)
        if formset_idioma.is_valid():
            for form in formset_idioma:
                idioma = form.cleaned_data.get('idioma')
                fluencia = form.cleaned_data.get('fluencia')
                if idioma and fluencia:
                    Idioma(
                        idioma=idioma,
                        fluencia=fluencia,
                        usuario=request.user
                        ).save()
        if formset_tecnologia.is_valid():
            for form in formset_tecnologia:
                sistema = form.cleaned_data.get('sistema')
                nivel = form.cleaned_data.get('nivel')
                if sistema and nivel:
                    Tecnologia(
                    sistema=sistema,
                    nivel=nivel,
                    usuario=request.user
                    ).save()                                          
    return render(request, "personal/curriculo.html", {
        'formset_idioma': formset_idioma,
        'formset_tecnologia': formset_tecnologia,})
```

template

```
<div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
     <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Idiomas</h5>
        </div>
        {{ formset_idioma.management_form }}
        <div class="content-inside" id="form_set_idioma">
            {% for form in formset_idioma %}
                {{form.non_field_errors}}
                {{form.errors}}
                <table class='no_error'>{{ form }}</table>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary fixedbutton" type="button" value="Adicionar" id="add_form_set_idioma">
        <div id="empty_form_set_idioma" style="display:none">
            <table class='no_error'>{{ formset_idioma.empty_form }}<br></table>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingFive">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Tecnologia</h5>
        </div>
        {{ formset_tecnologia.management_form }}
        <div class="content-inside" id="form_set_tecnologia">
            {% for form in formset_tecnologia %}
                {{form.non_field_errors}}
                {{form.errors}}
                <table class='no_error'>{{ form }}</table>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary fixedbutton" type="button" value="Adicionar" id="add_form_set_tecnologia">
        <div id="empty_form_set_tecnologia" style="display:none">
            <table class='no_error'>{{ formset_tecnologia.empty_form }}<br</table>
        </div>
    </div>



<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#add_form_set_idioma').click(function(){
var form_set_idioma_index = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();    $('#form_set_idioma').append($('#empty_form_set_idioma').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_set_idioma_index));
$('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_set_idioma_index) + 1);});

$('#add_form_set_tecnologia').click(function(){
var form_set_tecnologia_index = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();  $('#form_set_tecnologia').append($('#empty_form_set_tecnologia').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_set_tecnologia_index));
$('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_set_tecnologia_index) + 1);});
</script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhjvX.png

Comment: look at the POST parameters onSubmit. Maybe u are sending only 1 form.

Comment: But if im sending just 1 form, all datas of this form would be saved and the second form would be ignored, right? this is not happening @Zartch

Comment: I'm not sure what is your problem. Maybe if u show us the post parameters, it bring some clue.

Comment: You should use a [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) if you want to use more than one formset.

Comment: Can you explain to me about this prefix, or send a documentation please? @DanielRoseman

Comment: I linked you to the documentation.

Comment: ```formset_idioma = InsereIdiomaFormset(request.POST, prefix='formset_idioma')
        formset_tecnologia = InsereTecnologiaFormset(request.POST, prefix='formset_tecnologia')```
i did this change and didnt work. I read "Each formset’s prefix replaces the default form prefix that’s added to each field’s name and id HTML attributes." and 
I got a little confused

Comment: Okay, I did understand your question now. You're trying add new formsets  dynamically, right? @GustavoLisi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what @Daniel said, I've made some changes to your code and it's working just fine for me.

```
def cadastro_curriculo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset_idioma = InsereIdiomaFormset(request.GET or None, prefix='idiomas')
        formset_tecnologia = InsereTecnologiaFormset(request.GET or None, prefix='tecnologias')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset_idioma = InsereIdiomaFormset(request.POST, prefix='idiomas')
        formset_tecnologia = InsereTecnologiaFormset(request.POST, prefix='tecnologias')
        if formset_idioma.is_valid():
            for form in formset_idioma:
                idioma = form.cleaned_data.get('idioma')
                fluencia = form.cleaned_data.get('fluencia')
                if idioma and fluencia:
                    Idioma(
                        idioma=idioma,
                        fluencia=fluencia,
                        usuario=request.user
                        ).save()
        if formset_tecnologia.is_valid():
            for form in formset_tecnologia:
                sistema = form.cleaned_data.get('sistema')
                nivel = form.cleaned_data.get('nivel')
                if sistema and nivel:
                    Tecnologia(
                    sistema=sistema,
                    nivel=nivel,
                    usuario=request.user
                    ).save()
    return render(request, "image_app/curriculo.html", {
        'formset_idioma': formset_idioma,
        'formset_tecnologia': formset_tecnologia})
```

**template**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Student</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="curriculo_form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Salvar</button>
    <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
        <h5 class="mb-0">Idiomas</h5>
      </div>
      {{ formset_idioma.management_form }}
      <div class="content-inside" id="form_set_idioma">
        {% for form in formset_idioma %}
        {{form.non_field_errors}}
        {{form.errors}}
        <table class='no_error'>{{ form }}</table>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary fixedbutton" type="button" value="Adicionar" id="add_form_set_idioma">
      <div id="empty_form_set_idioma" style="display:none">
        <table class='no_error'>{{ formset_idioma.empty_form }}<br></table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingFive">
        <h5 class="mb-0">Tecnologia</h5>
      </div>
      {{ formset_tecnologia.management_form }}
      <div class="content-inside" id="form_set_tecnologia">
        {% for form in formset_tecnologia %}
        {{form.non_field_errors}}
        {{form.errors}}
        <table class='no_error'>{{ form }}</table>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary fixedbutton" type="button" value="Adicionar" id="add_form_set_tecnologia">
      <div id="empty_form_set_tecnologia" style="display:none">
        <table class='no_error'>{{ formset_tecnologia.empty_form }}<br</table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#add_form_set_idioma').click(function(){
        var form_set_idioma_index = $('#id_idiomas-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#form_set_idioma').append($('#empty_form_set_idioma').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_set_idioma_index));
        $('#id_idiomas-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_set_idioma_index) + 1);});

        $('#add_form_set_tecnologia').click(function(){
        var form_set_tecnologia_index = $('#id_tecnologias-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#form_set_tecnologia').append($('#empty_form_set_tecnologia').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_set_tecnologia_index));
        $('#id_tecnologias-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_set_tecnologia_index) + 1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why do you put id="curriculo_form"? Your code is exactly the same of mine, I dont even copy and didnt work @Eliakin

Comment: It's just an id, there's no purpose to it. I've just pressed `submitButton` and checked the database and data is there. @GustavoLisi

Comment: Did you add urls.py within your app?@GustavoLisi

Comment: But could you add multiple fields of the same form? I can save too, but if I click on "Adicionar" to duplicate my form, and submit, just the first is saved. I cant understand why this is happening

Comment: Solved, @GustavoLisi. It was your js script.

Comment: I've added the js script to the answer @GustavoLisi

Comment: I'm glad I could help you ˆ-ˆ